# Representing LinkedLists in UML diagrams?

Tags: java, uml

Wondering what is the format to represent this state of a class inside a UML diagram

```
private LinkedList<String> list;
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: [You should write code oriented to interfaces, not to specific classes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1065197)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a property with a multiplicity of 0..* and a type String. You generally don't design a linked list in UML, you use one to implement an association.